# Erros sendo gerados ao converter código python para exe com cx_freeze

Tags: python, api, .exe

Fiz a conversão do arquivo tucha.py para exe seguindo as instruções e com o seguinte setup.py:

```html
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name="tucha EXECUTABLE",
    version = "1.0.0",
    description = ".py to .exe",
    executables = [Executable("tucha.py")])
```

Esse é o erro que estou recebendo:

```
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 12, in <module>
__import__(name + "__init__")
File "C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 21, in <module>
scriptModule = __import__(moduleName)
File "tucha.py", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
from . import utils
File "C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
File "C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
File "C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
from .packages import chardet
File "C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
import urllib3
ImportError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

Para ser sincero não entendi muito bem o que está acontecendo,já procurei no google,porém os casos que aparecem não solucionaram o problema.

Answer (score -1):

Eu estou criando uma resposta pois não tenho reputação para fazer um comentário, eu estava com um problema muito parecido e consegui solucionar após horas buscando no stackoverflow.com(Em inglês, no pt não encontrei nada). Eu sou novato em Python então me desculpe se não souber lhe explicar da forma que entendi. Se houver como publique/edite o seu código do tucha.py ou se não puder mostrar o código, coloque ao menos o cabeçalho para que eu possa tentar lhe ajudar.
Eu vou deixar aqui uma sugestão do que pode lhe ajudar.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","tkinter","tkinter.filedialog","tkinter.messagebox"],
                     "includes": ["reportlab.pdfgen","reportlab.lib.units","subprocess","sqlite3"],
                     }

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "test",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "test application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("first.py", base=base,icon="icon.ico")])
```

Em **build_exe_options** as vezes é necessário definir bibliotecas que você está utilizando no seu script, o cx_freeze reconhece alguns, porém outros são necessários adicionar manualmente.